# /vendor/autoload.php not found when installing Laravel on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer. I installed composer in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www`.

I created a project using the create project command in composer. Once installed I went to the directory via terminal, `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravelproject`.

I entered `composer install` in the terminal. When I go to `localhost/www/laravelproject/public` I get this error message:

```
PHP Warning:
  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravelproject/vendor/autoload.php):  
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory
  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravelproject/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
  '/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravelproject/vendor/autoload.php'
  (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')
  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravelproject/artisan on line 18
```

I have looked all over Google, and stackoverflow for a solution, and all I've been able to find was to go to the root directory and enter composer install via terminal.

But that hasn't fixed the issue for me. Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

UPDATE: I ended up uninstalling composer, installing Apache2 and installing the dependencies that are show on the laravel website.

From there I reinstalled composer, and laravel, and used the /var/www/html section that the apache installation gave me. And it worked.

Comment: clearly, `composer install` failed

Comment: `composer install && composer dumpautoload` and see if that helps

Comment: I tried composer install && composer dumpautoload, and still get the same error.

If composer install failed, how can I install it successfully? I have spent quite a few hours looking for a solution. But it seems I may have a special case here?

Answer (score -2):

In the www folder try to give permission recursively all the laravel folder. You can execute command below

```
sudo chmod -R 777 laravelproject
```

EDIT: If it works, check chmod 644 for a file and 755 for a folder. However, the problem here is to understand whether this is the source of the error.

UPDATE: You may try followings too

```
$ php artisan config:cache
$ php artisan config:clear
$ composer dump-autoload -o
```

Comment: Giving write/execute permissions to everyone is a very big security risk and a Very Bad Idea

Comment: If a person is able to get into your server and touch to the files, chmod is not a lifeguard. Secure your files and directories with chmod as you want, but the database is wide open. Not always chmod 777 or 775 is dangerous.

Comment: So should I avoid this if I am only using it in my local system? I am a beginner, so I just want to practice with laravel. I have moved to my Windows machine, and will try to install it there. But I prefer installing it on my main machine that has Ubuntu.

Comment: @ChristianGutierrez If you are not running shared server, there is nothing to avoid about this situation. But do not forget to make those files secure.

Comment: It did not fix the problem.

Comment: @ChristianGutierrez I updated my answer, could you give a shot again and tell me the results

Comment: @AlperenÖzdemir I appreciate your help. I keep getting the same message.
When I enter:

`php artisan config:cache`
 
I get this error message.

`PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/artisan on line 18`

`PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/artisan on line 18`

Comment: Could you check manually /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/vendor/autoload.php file is exist or not

Comment: When I enter `php artisan serve` I get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/laravel/bootstrap/app.php on line 14`

Comment: @AlperenÖzdemir The file is there, and inside it it says: `<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit96b06755baad217877d27efabbcc4e1d::getLoader();`

Comment: Ohh damn, looks like complicated. Most probably artisan broke the composer process. Last chance for me, did you try composer install --no-scripts && composer update

Comment: @AlperenÖzdemir Just tried that now, no luck. I appreciate your time though. For now I'll just have to settle for using it on my Windows machine.

Comment: I am sorry @ChristianGutierrez, If I find anything you will hear it by me. Thank you.